# Accessing array with dynamic name inside a nested array typescript

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array

I have a nested array similar to this in a json where i wan to access the childarray that can be with a dynamic name

```
data=[
     {"childArray":{},"y":123456666666},
     {"childArray1":{},"y":123456666666},
     {"childArray2":{},"y":123456666666},
     {"childArray3":{},"y":123456666666},
     ]
```

Here is the snippet of code im trying to access the child array

```js
let childarray;
this.data.map(function(d)
        {
            let number= d.y;
            let array=d.this[childarray];
            console.log(array);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

access array which has given dynamically.
if you have to access particular one index and get value in given array.
Here is code for retrieve all data in given array.
I find problem solution for ac

```js
var data=[
     {"childArray":{"index":"value"},"y":123456666666},
     {"childArray1":{"index1":"value1"},"y":123456666666},
     {"childArray2":{"index2":"value2"},"y":123456666666},
     {"childArray3":{"index3":"value3"},"y":123456666666},
];
var childArray = "childArray1";
data.map(function(d)
{
  for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(d).length;i++){
     if(Object.keys(d)[i] == childArray) {
        console.log(d[Object.keys(d)[i]]) 
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: tried this and still getting same issue TypeError: Cannot read property 'childArray' of undefined